# Embed JS animation with functionality to another HTML5 page

Tags: javascript, css, html

I tried to clone this page as it is: https://www.canva.com/color-palette

The intention was to embed the color palette generator to another website.

I copied all JS, and CSS files to the PC and linked properly. Even the page is copied and use the external links as they are, animating part (which says "Try with our demo image") does not show the images and it displays only "alt"s.

I need to copy this page with it's color palette generating function.

Comment: You also need to ensure the images are copied over and update filepaths and references in HTML, CSS & JS code to reflect your own site's file structure.

Comment: There is a option  where user can upload an image an get the colours. That's what I need to copy basically.

Comment: yes, I know. But it can't get colours from a nonexistent image i.e. when the page loads with the example/default image prior to upload... you need to link something in to start with.